# add css and javascript in the twig child

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, twig

Hello I try to add some css and javascript in the twig child but it does not work.

head.html.twig :

```
{% stylesheets
            'bundles/mybundle/some_folder/css/myfile.min.css' filter='cssrewrite'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% block custom_sheets %}
{% endblock %}

<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
{% javascripts
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/some_folder/js/myfile.min.js'
%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

{% block custom_javascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

layout.html.twig:

```
<html>
<head>
    {% block head %}
        {%- include 'MyBundle:layout:head.html.twig' with {'_title': block('title') } -%}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
   ....

   {% block body %}
   {% end block %}

   .....
</body>
```

custom_layout.html.twig extends layout.html.twig :

```
{% block custom_sheets %}
  {% stylesheets
    'bundles/accueil/css/my.css' filter='cssrewrite'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/my.js'
    %}
      <script src="{{ asset_url }}" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Neither of my.css and my.js are loaded.

Why ?

Comment: Just call them in the  layout.html.twig. According to me, it's better to have all of the scripts and css files in the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of Twig. When you `include()` a template, the blocks of the included template are not available in the template which includes it. So the blocks defined in `head.html.twig` are lost.

That's why is common to not do an `include()` for the head and the footer of the page. Anyway, the layout.html.twig template is usually very large, so it doesn't matter to also include the header and footer contents.